# Group cohomology reference

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I'm interested in studying group cohomology (for discrete groups).

Are there accessible (lecture) notes that give a nice overview of the basics for group cohomology and develop the categorical machinery in the mean time?

My background: I am familiar with basic category theory and I have a vague understanding of some notions from homological algebra. I am familiar with abstract algebra (group theory, module theory, tensor products etc). I want to dive into the group cohomology right away, without having to spend much time on learning other things (if this is possible!).

Thanks for your recommendations!

Comment: I have written up [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_16_coho_course.pdf) myself. The classical reference is the book by [Kenneth S. Brown](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9327-6). Compare also with recommendations from [other posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697778/reference-for-group-cohomology) here.

Comment: Grochow & Qiao have a nice exposition on cohomology from the perspective of group theory and isomorphism testing (https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/15M1009767). The Handbook of Computational Group Theory (Holt, Eick, & O'Brien) is another good starting point. While these references are less comprehensive than standard texts, I find them to be a gentle introduction to the subject with some motivation.

Comment: you could also look at the group cohomology sections in the books on homological algebra by Rotman and Weibel

Comment: I also like the following lecture notes by Clara Löh: https://loeh.app.uni-regensburg.de/teaching/grouphom_ss19/lecture_notes.pdf. They are quite extensive (for lecture notes, that is) and cover the different points of view on group cohomology instead of clearly favoring one approach over the others. As a bonus, they also contain exercises in the end.

Comment: Out of curiosity: You've been quite active in the operator algebras tag. Any chance your interest in group cohomology is connected?

Comment: @MaoWao Not really. I also work a bit with categorical stuff that has nothing to do with operator algebras.